# jQuery - show only current ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, html-lists, children

im new to jQuery and have a slight issue with the following navigation:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Dh8j/7/

Essentially, I love the navigation in the Creative Production section of this lovely site: http://www.gainsburyandwhiting.com > see Portfolio > Fashion Show etc...

I need to hide the current ul and show a fresh one in its place. At the moment, they show until I un-click the parent.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Red

Comment: would you please elaborate more what you want to do?

Comment: to hide current one simply you can use `this.hide();`

Comment: Its about hiding cousins of the selected item, otherwise they show and hide on top of each other rather than only the selected one being in view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide all the `ul` elements that are descendant of the siblings of the current `ul` e.g.

```
$(this).siblings().find('ul').fadeOut('fast');
```

This finds each sibling of the clicked `ul` (all of which are `ul` in the example) and finds all the `ul` elements that are withing their bounds and fades them out.

In the context of your code:

```
$("nav ul li").find("ul").hide().end()
  .click(function(e) {
     if (this == e.target) {
       $(this).siblings().find('ul').fadeOut('fast');
       $(this).children('ul').fadeToggle('fast');    
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! That makes total sense, works a treat! I was thinking, is there are way to hide opened children when you go back the the start menu? ie, if you click on an level 1 then a level 2 the level 3 item shows, but then if you click on another level 1 item and then reselect the initial level 1 item, the level 3's are already open? Is there a way that the open/close starts from scratch each time you begin the process?

Comment: I realized that right after I got out. instead of immediate children you need to find all uls. I'll edit the answer right away.

Comment: Aleksi Yrttiaho - thank you so much, youre an absolute credit to why Stackoverflow works so well.